# AJAX function not getting called - Database not getting called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I'm trying to get my project running on the localhost. I'm having a problem with the built-in ajax function upon success. Here is the javascript function:

```
function getDecisions(page, searchstring) {
    page = typeof page !== 'undefined' ? page : 1;
    searchstring = typeof searchstring !== 'undefined' ? searchstring : '';

    $('.loading-container').show();
    if (searchstring != '') {
            params = searchstring;
    }
    else {
            params = getFilterObj();
            params['page'] = page;

            //Only get checked types
            $('#types input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
                    if ( $(this).is(":checked") ) {
                            params[$(this).attr("name")] = 'True';
                    }
            });
    }

    if ( $('input[name="approved-only"]:checked').val() == 'yes' ) {
            params['approved-only'] = 'yes';
    }

    $.ajax({
            url:'/dh',
            data: params,
            success: function(data) {
                    
                    info = data.info;
                    newhtml = '';

                    if (info.length == 0) {
                            newhtml += '<tr><td colspan="18" style="text-align: center;">No results returned</td></tr>\n';
                    }
...
}
```

I know that the javascript function is working as I'm stepping through until the very last line of the function, but I'm not even sure if the ajax function is being called. I'm getting the following Internal Server Error (500):

[image]

Can anyone say what could be causing a 500 error on the localhost for this type of an ajax call? Or how I might see whether the ajax function is being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ajax call is definitely being made. The reason I know this is because you are seeing the 500 server error. The 500 server error is a response from the server that means the request had some kind of error at the server. It looks like you are debugging in chrome. If that is the case, you can go to the Network tab in the developer tools and then as you step through your code, you will see an entry appear for that request. When the request completes, you will see the status update with error 500, which should match up with what you were seeing in the console. You can then click on that entry in the network tab, and hopefully be able to see the actual response from the server.

[image: An example web service call in chrome developer tools]

If you have control over the server, you might also be able to debug the webservice at that side and see what is going on.